# Edit script for user input rather than internal input

Tags: c, pointers, math, function-pointers

I have a simple script and it works fine. My question is, how can I get my results to display in a reduced simplified fraction? Also, at this point I am defining the values myself, is there a way to have the script ask the user to input the numerator and denominator for the different fractions used?

The posted script worked wonders for me in regards towards asking and performing the operations, so I am very thankful for that. It did not reduce the fractions, am I still missing something?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while(0!=b) { int r = a % b; a=b; b=r; }
    return a;
}
 int input(char* prompt) {
    int res;
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    scanf("%d", &res);
    return res;
}
 main()
 {
    int add,sub,mul,dd;
    int add1,sub1,mul1,dd1;
    int a,b,c,d;
    int fac = gcd(add, add1);
    a=input("Please enter the numerator for your first equation:");
    b=input("Please enter the denominator for your first equation:");
    c=input("Please enter the numerator for your second equation:");
    d=input("Please enter the denominator for your second equation:");
    add=(a*d+b*c);
    add1=(b*d);
    add /=fac;
    add1/=fac;
    printf("\The sum of your fractions is: %d/%d",add,add1);
    sub=(a*d-b*c);
    sub1=(b*d);
    printf("\nThe difference of your fractions is: %d/%d",sub,sub1);
    mul=(a*c);
    mul1=(b*d);
    printf("\nThe product of your fractions is: %d/%d",mul,mul1);
    dd=(a*d);
    dd1=(b*c);
    printf("\nThe quotient of your fractions is: %d/%d",dd,dd1);
 }
```

Comment: You can't declare functions inside other functions. I see you're going with a recursive solution.  if you don't know what "recursive solution" means -- or are uncomfortable writing your own -- it seems to me you are trying to do something that is significantly beyond your understanding of C.  You must walk before you run!  Copying in answers you don't understand how to write won't do you a lot of good.  Do you have a decent C textbook?  Go thru it until you get through loops -- or recursion -- and see what you'll write then.  Good luck.

Comment: See my updated answer. While the compiler may inline methods, they are all separate entities that should only depend on the stated input. They need not and should not be written where they are called.

Comment: It should work, what does the compiler say? Compiler option `-Wall` should complain about the form of the `main` definition. Are there other warnings/errors? You should also reduce the other operation results.

Comment: Remove the second declaration of `input` and work through all the compiler warnings and errors, they are (gcc) or should be sufficiently explicit.

Comment: No, the identifier `fac` is undeclared, there is no function mentioned in the error message. You need to declare it as `int`, as you declared `a,b,…,add,add1,…`.

Comment: The newly updated and edited post works perfectly! However, It did not reduce the fractions, am I still missing something? @LutzL

Comment: The program only does what you instruct it to do. So if there are no instruction for the reduction of the subtraction result, there will be no reduction. Etc. -- And: The computer does not have any metaphysical capabilities. It can not divine what value a variable will have before that value is computed. In C, variables are just dumb variables, not properties with bindings that automatically update after value changes.

Comment: How can j get the reduction process? With that I'll be done entirely.@LutzL

Comment: You just need to read carefully, the answers are already there.

Comment: I got it for the addition, but the remaining just don't work. @lutzl

Answer (score 0):

```
for each possible factor from 2 to min (numerator, denominator)
    while this factor evenly divides both numerator and denominator
        numerator   /= factor;
        denominator /= factor;
```

This will do it.  Actually, you could go up to `min (sqrt (numerator), sqrt (denominator))`, and that would work too.

Since you need it several times, best put it into a function and call it on each of your results.

Comment: You need also to account for multiple factors. Thus you will need to divide a found factor until it is no longer to be found in both numbers.

Comment: The algorithm above is in pseudocode.  You'll need to convert it to valid C, of course.  Presumably you know how to write for-loops and while-loops; if not, best review that before going further.

Comment: Good catch, Lutzl.  AraMod, I altered the code slightly to replace "if this factor..." with "while this factor..."  This means, for example, if you've got 20/20, it will factor out _all_ the 2's, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Euclidean algorithm. This is faster to compute the gcd of two numbers than trying out all possible prime factors.

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return  (0==b) ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

or

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while(0!=b) { int r = a % b; a=b; b=r; }
    return a;
}
```

Then apply, for instance for the sum, as

```
fac = gcd(add, add1); 
add /=fac; 
add1/=fac;
```

to get the reduced numbers.

---

To your other question, use the `atoi` function to transform argument string into numbers or use the `scanf` function to prompt for input. Be aware that no input verification is done by the C functions.

```
#include ...

int gcd(int a, int b) { ... }

int input(char* prompt) {
    int res;
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    scanf("%d", &res);
    return res;
}

int main() {
...
int a,b,c,d;
a = input("Number for a");
b = input("Number for b");
...
```

Comment: The gcd is the greatest common factor. To reduce the sum, do `fac = gcd(add, add1); add /=fac; add1/=fac;` to get the reduced numbers.

Comment: No, `gcd` is a function that is to be defined outside of main. Then you apply the reduction after you have computed the unreduced quantities. `int gcd(int a, int b) { return (0==b) ? a : gcd(b, a % b); } int main() { int add, add1; int a=-2, b=4, c=4, d=5;  add=(ad+bc); add1=(b*d); fac = gcd(add, add1); add /=fac; add1/=fac; printf(...`