# How can I get my fraction results reduced in this C Code?

Tags: c, math

Update 1: 
With everyone's help i was able to get:
-A point I would like to make, each int requires for a new role of definition. Have a look below to understand the mistake in answers and the solution in which I was going for.

If possibly can someone help me make this script continuous? By that I mean, after one expression is done and all the solutions are displayed, the user should be able to continue and keep using the script until they want to quit. Basically, how can I loop this whole thing so it does not end after one user input?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while(0!=b) { int r = a % b; a=b; b=r; }
    return a;
}
 int input(char* prompt) {
    int res;
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    scanf("%d", &res);
    return res;
}
 main()
 {
    int add,sub,mul,dd;
    int add1,sub1,mul1,dd1;
    int a,b,c,d;
    a=input("Please enter the numerator for your first equation");
    b=input("Please enter the denominator for your first equation");
    c=input("Please enter the numerator for your second equation");
    d=input("Please enter the denominator for your second equation");
    add=(a*d+b*c);
    add1=(b*d);
    int fac = gcd(add, add1);
        add /=fac;
        add1 /=fac;
    printf("\The sum of your fractions is: %d/%d",add,add1);
    sub=(a*d-b*c);
    sub1=(b*d);
    int red = gcd(sub, sub1);
        sub /=red;
        sub1 /=red;
    printf("\nThe difference of your fractions is: %d/%d",sub,sub1);
    mul=(a*c);
    mul1=(b*d);
    int red1 = gcd(mul, mul1);
        mul /=red1;
        mul1 /=red1;
    printf("\nThe product of your fractions is: %d/%d",mul,mul1);
    dd=(a*d);
    dd1=(b*c);
    int red2 = gcd(dd, dd1);
        dd /=red2;
        dd1 /=red2;
    printf("\nThe quotient of your fractions is: %d/%d",dd,dd1);
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit script for user input rather than internal input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787851/edit-script-for-user-input-rather-than-internal-input)

Comment: You need to move `int fac = gcd(add, add1);  add /=fac;   add1/=fac;` down to be below `add1=(b*d)` .  In C, statements like that don't define relations between variables; they are calculations that are executed immediately, and as such, you are just performing meaningless calculations with uninitialized variables that have no impact on the rest of the program.

Comment: That worked for the sum, what about the remaining? Do I essentially just repeat the same process just changing the variable? As an example for subtraction: 'int fac = gcd(sub, sub1); sub /=fac; sub1/=fac;' @M.M

Comment: That did not work, nor did inserting the sub, sub1 function into the same gcd(). I get the error of too many functions within the 'gcd()' @M.M

Comment: input is a numerator and denominator and the output should be a solution of arithmetic functions reduced to the lcd. So far the add and sub work but multiplication and division do not.

Comment: there is ambiguity in your method usage.. greatest common denominator is  not inclusive to fractions, just arithmetic.. you're second parameter is assumed to be a denominator. why? if `a` is `0`, the gcd should return `b`..  unless `b` is `0`.. then it's an exception. if `a` is suppose to be a numerator here, you're forced with trying to find a gcd of 0..

Comment: it's an exception because the answer is infinite..

Comment: @BrettCaswell I see what you mean. However, the script works fine and I was told if it works, done touch it.

Comment: @AraMod it should work equally well for all cases, you probably made a typo

Comment: It does, works perfectly fine the way it's displayed. If you had a chance can you show me how to get this in a loop form so the user can perform the task more than once. @M.M

Comment: @AraMod you could write a function, with same signature as the one in @stackptr 's answer, except inside the body, have `int x = gcd(*num, *den); *num /= x; *den /= x;`

Comment: Would that keep my script continuous? @M.M

Comment: bah.. I messed up my arithmetic.. GCD of 3/4 is not `GCD(3, 4)` it's `GCD(3/4)`, or `GCD(3/4, 0/4)`, which is `GCD(3, 0) / LCM(4, 4) = 3/4` .. GCD is step in the process of solving (arithmetic).. GCD (3, 0) is `3`

Comment: Hey Brett thanks for your reply. I was wondering, how can I get my script to loop after one set of equations is processed? @BrettCaswell

Comment: move your logic to another method, in your main start a while (true|false) loop that checks whether a variable (that you declared and initialized/assigned `true` before your loop), call your method.. perform another input check after your method call.. determine if that variable/response justifies setting the while check variable to false.

Comment: I'm lost, isn't it always true? Would I have to check for anything other than an end of the original statement? @BrettCaswell

Comment: `while (whileCheck) 
{
   RunMyMethods(); 
   whileCheck = input("Run again? (1 - yes, 0 - no)");
}`

Comment: And that goes directly below main or is it something that needs to be established outside of the main() @BrettCaswell

Comment: @AraMod within `main` closure. program ends at the end of `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recalculate your gcd for each specific case and then divide:

```
    add=(a*d+b*c);
    add1=(b*d);
    int fac = gcd(add, add1);
    add /=fac;
    add1/=fac;
    printf("\The sum of your fractions is: %d/%d",add,add1);
    sub=(a*d-b*c);
    sub1=(b*d);
    fac = gcd(sub,sub1);
    sub /= fac;
    sub1 /= fac;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify a fraction:

```
void simp(int *num, int *den)
{
    int i;

    int lim = (*num < *den) ? *num : *den;
    for (i = 2; i < lim; ++i)
        if (*num % i == 0 && *den % i == 0) {
            *num /= i;
            *den /= i;
        }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this portion figured out, thanks for your help. My follow up question now that my script works, how do I get it to loop so that after one set of results are displayed, the user can start over until they type "quit" as the first numerator? @stackptr

Comment: The gcd function already exists; no need to reinvent the wheel